# Prove that $\sup \{ \varepsilon x:\, x\in A\}=\varepsilon \sup A$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Since this is an introductory course to real analysis I am looking for the most simple and direct proof. Based mostly on definitions.

Let $\varepsilon$ be a positive real number. If $A$ is a non-empty bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $B = \{\varepsilon x : x \in A\}$ then $\sup(B) = \varepsilon \sup(A)$.

Since $A$ is a non-empty subset if follows that $\sup(A)$ exists as a finite supremum. Which by definition means that $x \leq \sup(A)$ for all $x\in A$ and by the second multiplicative property since $\varepsilon$ is positive it follows that $\varepsilon x \leq \varepsilon \sup(A)$ which means that $\sup(B) \leq \varepsilon \sup(A)$.

The hard part is to show that $\sup(B) \geq \varepsilon \sup(A)$ I can't think of a way to go about that.

So maybe a one shot deal... it's true always that $$\varepsilon x = \varepsilon x \space \space  \forall x \in A, \space \varepsilon \gt 0 \in \mathbb{R}$$
It's also true by algebraic manipulation and associativity that $(\varepsilon x )= ((\varepsilon)(x))$ by associativity. So it follows that $\sup(B) = ((\varepsilon) (\sup(A))$

To me I don't see any issue with showing $\varepsilon x = \varepsilon x$ can lead to the conclusion of the statement.

Comment: Since $\text{Sup}(B) \ge \epsilon x$ for all $x\in A$, then $\text{Sup}(B)/\epsilon \ge x$ for all $x\in A$, hence $\text{Sup}(B)/\epsilon \ge \text{Sup}(A)$.

Comment: for the second part when you go from $(\epsilon x)=((\epsilon)(x))$ to claim the two supremums are equal, that is where you are making an error because you are pretty much using the very fact you want to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\epsilon >0.$

Show that $\epsilon \sup A \le \sup B;$

1)$B \not =\emptyset$ , bounded;

$ \sup B$ exists.

2) $\epsilon x \le \sup B$, $x \in A$.

$x \le (1/\epsilon) \sup B$, $x \in A$.

$(1/\epsilon) \sup B$ is an upper bound for $x$.

Hence $\sup A \le (1/\epsilon) \sup B$

Comment: Straight forward and simple

Comment: K.Gibson Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid heavy notation, let $s=\sup A$, which exists because $A$ is bounded.

Consider $b\in B$. Then, by definition, there exists $a\in A$ with $b=\epsilon a$. In particular $a\le s$, and so $b=\epsilon a\le \epsilon s$. It follows that $\epsilon s$ is an upper bound of $B$.

Let $u$ be an upper bound of $B$. Then $u/\epsilon$ is an upper bound of $A$ (prove it) and so $u/\epsilon\ge s$. Therefore $u\ge \epsilon s$.

Answer (score 1):

> So maybe a one shot deal... it's true always that
>   εx=εx  ∀x∈A, ε>0∈R

That's *SOOOO* close.

Note: that since $\epsilon > 0$ then we will have $c < d\iff c\epsilon < d\epsilon$ and that for $a = \frac b\epsilon \in A \iff b = a\epsilon \in B$.

And using these facts it is just a matter of pointing out the facts (and just the facts, ma'am)..

1) $A$ is non-empty if and only if $B = \{\epsilon a| a \in A\}$ is non-empty.  And $A$ is non-empty, so $B$ is non empty.

2) $A$ is bounded above by some $C$ if and only if $B$ is bounded above by some $\epsilon C$.

If we want a bit more detail $A$ bounded above by $C$ means for all $a \in A$ that $a \le C$.  So for all $b \in B$ where $b = \epsilon a$ for some $a \in A$ that $b \le \epsilon C$.  That is, by definition $B$ is bounded above by $\epsilon C$.

3) By least upper bound property of reals $\sup A$ exists if 1) and 2) are satisfied so $\sup B$ exists if and only $\sup A$ exists.

4)  $C$ is an upper bound of $A$ if and only if $\epsilon C$ is an upper bound of $B$ because.... oh, I guess we already said that two bullet points above.

5) $y=\frac w\epsilon  < \sup A$ if and only if $w =  y\epsilon < \epsilon \sup A$ and if $y < \sup A$ means $y = \frac w\epsilon$ isn't an upper bound, then that would be true exactly if $w =  y \epsilon < \epsilon \sup A$ would mean $w$ is not an upper bound of $B$.

So $M = \sup A$ if and only if $\epsilon M = \sup B$.

.....

It's kind of tempting to notice that since $\sup A$ is an upper bound of $A$ then $\epsilon \sup A$ is an upper bound of $B$ so $\epsilon \sup A \ge \sup B$ and then figure you must prove $\epsilon \sup A \le \sup B$.

This isn't actually nescessary and can get you off on irrelevant tangents.  But you can do it:

If $\sup B < \epsilon \sup A$ then

$\frac {\sup B}\epsilon < \sup A$ so $\frac {\sup B}\epsilon$ is not an upper bound of $A$.

So there is an $a \in A$ so that $\frac {\sup B}\epsilon < a \le \sup A$.

So $\sup B < a\epsilon \le \epsilon \sup A$. But $a\epsilon \in B$ so that is a contradiction.

But really, the  "one shot deal" is much cleaner and ... not as misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is more important here to build intuition first as to what is being said, and why it should be true.  Thy key is to understand the geometry of $\{ \epsilon x \; : \; x \in A\}$.  For brevity, denote the latter set by $\epsilon A$.

So, consider first the special case when $A$ is a closed interval: $A = [a_{1}, a_{2}]$.  What is $\epsilon A$? It is the interval
$$
[\epsilon a_{1}, \epsilon a_{2}].
$$

Generally, if $A$ not necessarily an interval, but is just known to be nonempty and bounded, and $a_{1}, a_{2}$ are its elements with $a_{1} \leq a_{2}$, then multiplication by a positive $\epsilon$ preserves the latter inequality:
$$
\epsilon a_{1} \leq \epsilon a_{2}.
$$

Thus, for a general (nonempty, bounded) $A$ and a positive $\epsilon$, the set $\epsilon A$ is the one that results from a rescaling of $A$ **that preserves the ordering**.

This boldfaced property of the rescaling directly implies that the rescaling also preserves the greatest upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with a minimum, $m$, then $\epsilon m \leqslant \epsilon x$ for all $x \in S$, i.e. the set $\epsilon S$ has the minimum $\epsilon m$.

If $S$ is the set of all upper bounds of $A$, then $\epsilon S$ is the set of all upper bounds of $\epsilon A$, and the result follows.